# Xna Texture3D loading

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I am trying to load texture3D(tga). I used tga from http://xbox.create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=43 and i load texture with:

```
Content.Load<Texture3D>("path to TGA")
```

When I debug i get an error saying that I am **trying to load texture2D as texture3D**. Anyone knows what is the problem?

and btw i'm also wondering if its possible to make texture3D from 1 color.

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) `Texture3D` cannot be loaded with the `ContentManager`.

Comment: But I don't get any error for not loading it properly. If this isn't the right way then how?

Comment: A TGA file is a 2D image file. It's not 3D. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! You don't even have to load texture because the location of it is already stored in model(fbx file) and it is loaded automatically. :D

Thanks Nico Schertler for showing me that link!